# Как поместить функцию в класс состояния FSM Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Всем привет, нужна помощь хочу сделать машину состояния, с функцией внутри.
Уже все попробовал но функция не работает, отдельно без машины состояний все четко работает.
Зарание спасибо!

```
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
from create_bot import dp, bot
from func1 import func


async def start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Приветствую! Выберите нужную вам функцию.")


class Form(StatesGroup):
    seturl = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['Проверка'])
async def test(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply('Введите значение')
    await Form.seturl.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=Form.seturl)
async def monet(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    testget = func(message.text)
    if testget == "true":
        await message.answer("Есть!")
    else:
        await message.answer('Нет!')
    
    await state.finish()


def register_handlers(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(start_command, commands=['start'])
```

Comment: Какая функция должна быть в машине состояний? И что она должна выполнять?

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понимаю зачем вам функция внутри класса состояния, но вот:

```py
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup

from data import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


class Form(StatesGroup):
    @staticmethod
    def test(parametr):
        print(parametr)

    seturl = State()


@dp.message_handler(commands=['Проверка'])
async def test(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply('Введите значение')
    await Form.seturl.set()
    Form.test(1)  # ВОТ ТУТ! Все работает


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```